# Type mismatch error when testing inherited constructors

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, subclass

I am using eclipse. When i tried to test a class using Junit I get an error when trying to create an object.

```
    public abstract class Property {

    private int number = 0;
    private String street = null;
    private String city = null;
    private String postCode = null;
    private int numberOfRooms = 0;

    public Property(int number, String street, String city, String postCode, int numberOfRooms) {...}
    ...
}
```

```
    public class House extends Property {

    public House(int number, String street, String city, String postCode, int numberOfRooms) {
        super(number, street, city, postCode, numberOfRooms);
    }
   ...
}
```

This is the junit test file:

```
public class PropertyTest {

@Test
    public void testHouse() {
        Property house = new House(1, "Percy Road", "London", "WC2N 5DU", 2);
        assertEquals("1 Percy Road, London WC2N 5DU (2 bedroom house)", house.toString());
    }
}
```

And I get this error in PropertyTest: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from House to Property**.
To my knowledge this code should work

Comment: What package is `Property` in? Are you certain you are importing the correct class?

Comment: All of them are in the same package

Comment: I just deleted the test file and created another one from scratch and now it works. I don't why I haven't tried this before. Thanks

Comment: Side note: unless you really want to test your toString implementation, avoid writing such tests. If you want to test the content of objects, use getters.

Comment: The problem was probably an erroneous import statement importing the wrong `Property` class.